# Unable to run and give input to C code through Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want to run a C code through Java to print an integer which is entered by the user. I'm using **ProcessBuilder** class.

The Java code gives the same output (stdout:0) for every integer that I input through `outputstream`.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String line;
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("first1.exe");
        Process process = builder.start();
        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
        InputStream err=process.getErrorStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
        writer.write(8);
        writer.flush();
        line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Stdout: " + line);
    }
}
```

I always get the output:

```
stdout:0
```

The C code for **first1.exe** is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
process.waitFor();
writer.write(8+"\n");
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code when the C code `first1.exe` executes, it waits for an input to be given.

Here the writer just writes **8** and does nothing while the code `first1.exe` requires the user to write **8** and press enter.

The above code does not work because enter or newline is not given.
Replacing the line `writer.write(8);` with `writer.write(8+"\n");` and add `process.waitFor()` before `writer.write(8+"\n")` and it will work properly.

On replacing the statement, the code gives `stdout:8` as output.